# Why does Mjolnir fall down in Age of Ultron but not in Endgame?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron, avengers-endgame, mjolnir

In a scene in *Avengers: Age of Ultron*, we saw Quicksilver trying to take Mjolnir during its flight and suddenly the hammer fell, taking with it Quicksilver to the ground.

But in *Avengers: Endgame*,

> Spider-Man grabs the hammer in flight with his web and the hammer continue its flight without falling.

Is he worthy? Is it because he didn't really touch the hammer? Or is it the will of Thor which maintains the hammer in flight? Or anything else?!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The enchantment placed on Mjolnir by Odin is as follows:

> Whosoever holds this hammer, if he be worthy, shall possess the power of Thor.
>
> <sub>*Thor*</sub>

Quicksilver tries to wield Mjolnir and seeing as he isn't worthy, at least at this moment in time (he probably is later when he sacrifices himself), it starts to fall to the floor and due to how fast both are travelling he is thrown to the ground and away from it.

It's also worth noting, as Xantec mentions in a comment, that Mjolnir has a similar affect on Hulk in *The Avengers* to Quicksilver when he grabs onto it. Just Hulk is stronger and manages to keep hold as it falls to the floor.

Spider-Man on the other hand never tried to wield or even touch Mjolnir, he just webs onto it. Therefore, the enchantment's effects don't kick in on him.

Comment: Of course, in Thor: Ragnarok it is stated that the enchantment keeping Hela imprisoned ends with Odin's death.  It is entirely possible that the "worthiness" enchantment is simply not active during the Odineternalsleep...  (***~Runs for cover from Cap's fans~***)

Comment: @Chronocidal Isn't the implication that Odin was continually trying to keep her imprisoned rather than a one time enchantment like with Mjolnir?

Comment: *affect -> effect (in «Mjolnir has a similar affect on Hulk»)

Comment: Do we know that Spider-Man isn't Worthy, though? If Captain America is, I wouldn't be surprised if Spider-Man was, as well. His motto is "With great power, comes great responsibility," after all, and that was basically the lesson that Odin was trying to teach Thor in Thor 1.

Comment: There's an implication that being worthy means not just being responsible, but also willing to kill if necessary (and wise enough to know when it's not necessary, and how, if possible, to _make_ it not necessary).  So, @nick012000, Spider-Man might not count because of that, since he usually isn't willing to kill.  Then again, there are also implications that leadership ability is what makes one worthy, and Spider-Man kinda fits that bill, thanks to his motto.  It's a tough call, really.

Answer (score 63):

### Spider-Man does not grab the hammer in flight. He webs it as it flies by, and it pulls him along. He isn't physically trying to wield it (by grabbing the handle).

It can be seen quickly here:

Without an actual screen cap from the movie, I present you with this video.

Comment: As supporting evidence, see [here](https://youtu.be/4J-JObkgK7k) when Hulk tries to catch Mjolnir by the handle in Avengers (2012). The hammer drops to the ground (after an inertial distance) rather than continuing to fly.

Comment: ...does that mean if he picks it up by the head, it can be moved? Or what if it's one of those automatic toilet lids? Does that mean the toilet lid is worthy?

Comment: So... the web is worthy?

Comment: @Ben That's one thing that's been discussed in one of the movies (after the Vision incident). One of the scenarios they presented was "If you put the Mjollnir in an elevator, will it be able to lift it? Is the elevator worthy?" In the end, Odin's curse was about wielding the power of Thor; there's probably some wiggle room in the curse's understanding of what "wield" means. And "who", if we're talking about toilet lids :P Really, magic is always implied to have some level of intelligence, that's something that pretty clearly separates advanced technology (in a non-AI universe) from magic :D

Comment: @Luaan haha yeah that was the joke I was referring to

Comment: @Luaan Plus we've seen a variety of floors and planet surfaces have no trouble holding up Mjolnir.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy It would be quite difficult to use it if you had to summon it from the planet's core every time, after all.

Comment: Thor hangs the hammer on a coat hook in Thor 2

Comment: @Ellesedil Is the coat hanger worthy?

Comment: @JackBNimble Could you please confirm that you are the copyright holder of that image as you claimed when you uploaded that image?

Comment: @DavidMulder I have added the citation for the content creator. Although I don't believe I claimed to be the copyright holder, as there is nothing indicating that when I attach an image.

Comment: I am the copyright holder on the image in this other answer though, if that helps.  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26599/in-wall-e-why-does-everyone-get-thrown-when-the-axiom-suddenly-lists/26618#26618

Comment: @JackBNimble Please check the edit summary on my edit when I removed the image. User publications on SE have to be licensed under a CC 3.0 BY-SA and you can't exclude a portion of the contribution. As you don't have the copyright you can't publish it under CC 3.0 BY-SA (nor was it published under a compatible license by the original copyright holder)... point is: You can't add it to a site like this.

Comment: @DavidMulder I don't understand why are singling my answer out. I do not claim to be the copyright holder, I linked to the original video. I do not profit from this, the content creator does lose money from this. Why aren't you going after TheLethalCarrot's answer, or do you believe either he or eddide9 are the copyright holders of that clip from the Avenger's movie? Wouldn't this fall under the category of fair use? I removed the image and did a link to their video, which, since it is on Youtube, is perfectly fine, since their whole business model is to generate views (both host and creator).

Answer (score 5):

No.

Take note, Quicksilver was running so fast he basically stopped time. He didn't catch Mjolnir mid-air, but rather tried to hold and wield it.

Spider-Man, on the other hand, was in the same time frame as Mjolnir, and just got brought along for the ride.

Comment: This is not a yes/no question.

Comment: I didn't respond with a yes or no, did I?

Comment: @isanae The last paragraph of the question begins with the question "Is he worthy?" I believe XanderX is responding to that with "No."

Comment: I was going to edit my response, but, didn't get it in within 5 minutes. At any rate, you are correct, that I was responding to the question as a whole, and I responded with more than just "no."